# Fetch data From Mysql using ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

My code is this

```
db_con =Mysql.new('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'user')
obj = db_con.query("select * from users where id=1 limit 1")
title=obj.fetch_hash["title"]
```

it gives result but my title is in Russian language e.g(знак ударения, znak udareniya)
it gives us

```
title =???? ????????, znak udareniya
```

in my db it stored `,знак ударения, znak udareniya`

how can i solve this problem please suggest me

Comment: Have you got '# encoding: utf-8' at the beginning of your file?

Comment: if you use `rails dbconsole` `select * users where id = 1`, does the name show correctly?

Comment: Yes name is showing correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use

```
 db_con =Mysql.new('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'user')
    db_con.query("set names utf8")
    obj = db_con.query("select * from users where id=1 limit 1")
    title=obj.fetch_hash["title"]
```

and i found original results

Answer (score 0):

Change your encoding in DB to utf8 or create a new db:

```
$ mysql -u USER -p
create database YOURDB_NAME_development CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```